# AJAX seems to be unable to GET AWS API Gateway even with CORS enabled

Tags: ajax, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have made an API Gateway which calls a lambda function on AWS.  The link to GET it is:

https://z4eiy7g9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/rotation

Clicking it should return a number bigger than 6000.  I want to use Javascript to GET the API and my understanding is I need to use AJAX to do that.  So, I have the following javascript (importing jQuery 3.1.1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
         url: "https://z4eiy7g9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/rotation",
         headers: {"Content-Type": "text/json"},
         type: "GET",
         success: function() { alert('Success!'); }
      });
    });
});
```

This doesn't work because of cross-origin stuff and so my understanding is I need to enable CORS.  So, I followed the instructions in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html.  I have

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin*: '*'
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type'
```

My understanding of this is that the origin can be any domain and the only header that needs to be included is 'Content-Type'.  However, when I click my button to trigger this event, I get the following error in my console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://z4eiy7g9n0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/rotation.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://****' is therefore not allowed access. The
>   response had HTTP status code 403.

Now, I can call the API from R using the `httr` package, so I know it can be called from at least some systems.

What am I doing wrong with either my AJAX request or with my API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had not deployed the modified resources with CORS enabled.  Once I deployed the resource, the javascript started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used AJAX to connect to a CORS-enabled API, and I don't remember passing content-type in the headers. Have you tried `application/json` instead of `text/json`? I believe this is how it gets configured by the CORS wizard on the AWS console.